# Redirect multiple subdomains over https

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I think my problem can be fixed by a correct `.htaccess` configuration or a PHP redirect (Laravel framework).

I have a website with about 20 countries. If I want to go to the United States the link is: www.mysite.com/?d=US

So I create 20 subdomains like: "us.mysite.com", "uk.mysite.com", "germany.mysite.com", "france.mysite.com"..

All the subdomains points to `/` and works fine.

I have my `.htaccess` configured to redirect "http" to "https" and it works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

I try this and should work ... but is not .. even when I make it work for only one country.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^us.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://us.mysite.com/?d=US [R=301,NC,N]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^germany.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://germany.mysite.com/?d=DE [R=301,NC,N]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^france.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://france.mysite.com/?d=FR [R=301,NC,N]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^uk.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://uk.mysite.com/?d=UK [R=301,NC,L]
```

I think it is some conflict with the first redireccion (SSL) .. the https. I go to "us.mysite.com" and nothings happens .. I get only "https://us.mysite.com" without "/?d=US"..

How can I fix that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `HTTPS_HOST`, only `HTTP_HOST`. You also have to prevent an infinite loop. I put your HTTPS redirect at the end and set it up so country URLs don't get a double redirect when visited on HTTP. Here it is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)d=US(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://us.mysite.com/?d=US [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^germany.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)d=DE(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://germany.mysite.com/?d=DE [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^france.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)d=FR(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://france.mysite.com/?d=FR [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uk.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)d=UK(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://uk.mysite.com/?d=UK [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)d=
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But can't you just check the `HTTP_HOST` in your code instead of needing the `d` param?

Another thing is that this is dropping any request URI that is requested. Don't you want to keep them as you do in your HTTPS redirect?